# Updating Enterprise apps on iPads enrolled in Apple's MDM server?

Tags: ipad, applications, server.app, mobile-device-management, enterprise

So I'm running into a weird issue here when trying to update an internal Enterprise app to a newer version with Apple's MDM server. Profile Manager runs on 10.9.2 and Server.app 3.0.3 and we've tested multiple apps across multiple managed devices.

The web interface says all devices are updating, but what I see now is that even when it has said it has updated the app on a device, if the app was running then the MDM server seem to think it has updated it while in reality the old app is still on the device.

Anybody else experience this? What did you do to get around it?

Comment: What version of server app and what version of OS are running Profile Manager?

Comment: Latest of both. 10.9.2 and 3.0.3.

I see this with multiple different apps and on multiple devices.